# Aurelia layouts is replacing its parent element

Tags: aurelia

I have this Aurelia project where I have 2 layouts.
My main layout looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <slot name="aside-content"></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <slot name="main-content"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

on X module I have this:

```
<template>
  <require from="./client-list"></require>

  <div slot="main-content">
    <div class="no-selection text-center">
      <h2>${message}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div slot="aside-content">
    <div class="row">
      <client-list class="col-md-12"></client-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Aurelia is replacing the contents on the respective placeholder, but it is also replacing its div parent element breaking the whole design.

I'm getting something like `router-view > div#main-content + div#aside-content` where the expected results would be `router-view > ( div.col-md-4 > div#aside-content ) + ( div.col-md-8 > div#main-content )`

I don't know whether it is the expected behavior or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your example and how you are using your components. Could you reproduce the issue in a gist? Use this as a base https://gist.run/?id=5a9c5cda449bfe3789a58122372a0a20

Comment: I just updated it. on layout-default.html i set up some <p> tags which are not included when aurelia runs. besides that. I added a class to its div parent; if you inspect the results, you will see that div with "parent-element" class is not present in DOM

Comment: I need to see the link

Comment: https://gist.run/?id=986033f5fd94644ad95f5cbd4abb281e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `<router-view layout-view="default.html"></router-view>` to specify the layout view.

See this example https://gist.run/?id=a75d76272316ca25513802bda8d225d1

Comment: thank you. Aurelia should update its docs. I count not find that anywhere